# Migrate from appsettings.json to ARM

Tags: .net-core, azure-resource-manager, appsettings

**Scenario**
I host my *Net Core 3.1* WebApp Aplication on a Linux App Service Plan on Azure.
I use some library which needs to have provided some settings object in `appsettings.json` like this:

```
"Container": {
  "Settings1": "val1",
  "Settings2": "val2"
}
```

How to provide those appsettings in ARM template? I have tried:

```
"appSettings": [
  {
    "name": "Container:Settings1",
    "value": "val1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Container:Settings2",
    "value": "val2"
  },
```

but `:` does not help me set those settings in way that is needed for those third party library

Comment: Does double underscore instead of : work?

Comment: Yes it works thank you. I found this solution hours ago :)

Comment: @zolty13 Glad to know you have it working now. Please post what worked for you as an answer below so it helps others in the community as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reason that I use Linux Web App, it is needed to set appSettings with double underscore `__` instead of colon `:`

```
"appSettings": [
  {
    "name": "Container__Settings1",
    "value": "val1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Container__Settings2",
    "value": "val2"
  },
```